# Crystal Reports Visual Studio connect to AS/400 DB2

Tags: ibm-midrange, crystal-reports-xi

I have wriiten a Crystal Reportstype of user front end using Visual Studio. I have to access data from AS/400 Db2. I am looking for tips how to code the connections strings for a Stored Procedure or a view. Specifically, HOw do i determine the server name. and the database name. Is the database name the Library name?

Comment: Yes, the database name is the library name. The server name is something that would have to be given to you.

Comment: I see, ok i can ask that. there is no way to determine on your own this server name?

Comment: I suppose it depends on the network where the IBM i lives. The network I'm using right now at work there's no way you'd be able to figure out the server name. You wouldn't know if you were connecting to an IBM i, a linux box, etc. And even if I could figure out that "Y76382" was an IBM i I wouldn't know if it was a production box, a development box, a QA box, etc.

Comment: If you know the IP address, you can use that instead of the server name.